# How to use Mocha to test on client-side WebSocket? Receiving a ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

Tags: javascript, websocket, mocha.js

I am writing a wrapper around the HTML5 WebSocket object, and I am testing the entire project (the node server side and the client side) with `mocha`.

When I run my tests against my wrapper, I get a `ReferenceError: WebSocket` is not defined from `mocha`. I think that is something related to the fact that `mocha` is used to test node stuff, but I can't find something that confirm my hipothesis and show me how to properly setup my test environment.

Right now everything is very simple, my test script is just:

```
"test": "mocha --recursive 'src/**/__tests__/*.js'"
```

My wrapper is:

```js
function Signal() {
  this.socket = null
}

Signal.prototype.connect = function connect(url) {
  this.socket = new WebSocket(url)
}
```

My tests are just checking if calling the connect method with a non-responding server blows:

```js
// I use chai as assertion library
describe('connect', () => {
  it('blows if the server doesn\'t exist or respond', () => {
    const signal = new Signal()
    const connect = () => signal.connect('wss://fakeurl:12345')
    expect(connect).to.throw()
  })
})
```

I also tried with jest. It doesn't throw the `ReferenceError` but always tells me that the test is passing... even if I manually throw an error in the `connect` method.

What am I missing? Any idea?